# How Linux namespaces are separated?

Tags: linux, namespaces, containers

I'm trying to understand linux namespace.

Question 1. About Global(initial) Namespace.

Figure.1 shows the process of creating a new UTS namespace1 after clone() in process P1 and putting the newly created process2 into UTS namespace1.
Figure.2 is the same process as Fig.1, but the picture is slightly different. Fig.1 shows the newly created UTS namespace as if it were a separate space. Fig.2 shows the initial UTS namespace containing the newly created UTS namespace1.

I'm wondering which of the two pictures is right.
Usually there is a global mount namespace in the mount namespace, and now there are multiple namespaces in it, so can UTS be the same?

[image: Question1_picture]

Question 2. Using multiple flags with clone() to create namespace

`int child_pid = clone(child_main, child_stack+STACK_SIZE, CLONE_NEWUTS | CLONE_NEWIPC | SIGCHID, NULL);`

If I use multiple(UTS, IPC) flags to create new namespace using clone() system call, new process made by clone() belong to UTS namespace and IPC namespace?

[image: Question2_picture]

Comment: Q1, some types of namespace are structured as tree, namespaces of these type have parent and children namespace. some are not, just isolated namespaces. Q2, UTS and IPC are type of namespace, not namespace instance.

Comment: @ZangMingJie Thanks for the reply. Can you tell me which namespaces are tree or not?(PID, Mount namespaces are tree..?) And doesn't `clone()` or `unshare()` system call create a new namespace after all?


See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/namespaces.7.html



    clone(2)
    ...If the flags
    argument of the call specifies one or more of the CLONE_NEW*
    flags listed below, then new namespaces are created for each
    flag, and the child process is made a member of those
    namespaces.